# BindingSource error with relation dataset

Tags: c#

I have two tables: Customer and Order. I fill the tables to dataset, add relation to dataset and bind to datasources:

```
var customerDs = _customerDAO.ExecuteSelectCommand(_customerCmd.SelectCommand, _customerCmd.TableName);
var orderDs = _orderDAO.ExecuteSelectCommand(_orderCmd.SelectCommand, _orderCmd.TableName);

_ds = new DataSet();

_ds.Tables.Add(customerDs.Tables[0].Copy());
_ds.Tables.Add(orderDs.Tables[0].Copy());

var relation = new DataRelation("CustomerOrderRelation", _ds.Tables["Customer"].Columns["id"],
                            _ds.Tables["CustomerOrder"].Columns["Customer_id"]);
_ds.Relations.Add(relation);

_customerBs = new BindingSource();
_customerBs.DataSource = _ds;
_customerBs.DataMember = "Customer";

_orderBs = new BindingSource();
_orderBs.DataSource = _customerBs;
_customerBs.DataMember = "CustomerOrderRelation";
```

But the error

> "DataMember property 'CustomerOrderRelation' cannot be found on the
>   DataSource" thrown on "_customerBs.DataMember =
>   "CustomerOrderRelation";"

What the problem? I can't figure that out!